# Runnable jar with Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, java

I'm trying to export my program as a runnable jar, packing the necessary libraries (Apache POI). The .jar is created, but it doesn't work. Is there a catch on deploying with these libraries? Because the program itself runs great from eclipse.

Comment: Can you take us through the steps you took to build the JAR?  And can you be more specific about how "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Export->Runnable jar->Extract required libraries->Finish. The program starts up, but when It should start using the libraries to read an excel file - nothing happens.

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Are you running from the command line (`java -jar myJAR.jar`)?

Comment: Just checked, just one error when the program has to use the read file: a null pointer. My guess is that the file isn't read whatsoever, because the reading takes about 10 sec, it "reads" instantly when using the jar.. :|

Comment: Is the read file inside the JAR, or where is it?  How does the program know where the read file is?  I think your question needs to include more information (and code) before we can really give you any specific help.

Comment: The program runs from eclipse, but not from the .jar, so the code is runnable. The user selects the excel file, which then is read, in the .jar case not read.

Comment: Again, I think we need to see some code showing how the file is located and read in.  At this point I don't think it's a problem with the way the JAR is packaged but rather the way your code locates and reads in the file.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was indeed in the read function. The file chooser wasn't giving the full path, all is well now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few questions to ask yourself in this situation:

- Where does the program fail?  Are there any errors in the console? Are you running from the command line (`java -jar myJAR.jar`) so that you can see console output?
- Okay, so you get a NullPointerException for the read file. Is the read file inside the JAR, or where is it? How does the program know where the read file is?
- Is there really a problem with the way the JAR is packaged, or is it the way your code locates and reads in the file?  Perhaps your code assumes a relative location which cannot be resolved when run from the JAR.

Answer (score 2):

There are the following strategies.

1. Create your jar. Put it to chosen directory. Put there all dependencies of your application. Create script (shell script, batch file etc depending on your platform) where the `java` command line is either written hard coded or is generated. The line must include the class path, e.g.
   `java -cp myapp.jar;poi.jar com.company.MyMain`
2. Create indeed runnable jar, i.e. jar that can be executed using command like `java -jar myapp.jar`. If your application has dependencies this jar must have `MANIFEEST.MF` file that defines class path using property `Class-Path`
3. Pack all your classes and all your dependencies into one large jar file.

Obviously all these operations should be automated either home made script or by one of available build tools.